# Add element changes in laravel in separate table?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I have a classic create() function to create elements, but changes I wish to save in a separate table, like history. There is table: element_changes and also model created named ElementChange, but in my ElementController, how can I tell to save it in a separate table?

Classic create function:

```
public function create(Request $request) 
    $item = new Item();
    $item->fill($request->old());
    return view('items.create', compact('item'));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to tell your model to create the new item

```
$item->fill($request-old())->create();
```

Comment: Thank you, but is this not in Controller to do? I have at the moment in my Model $fillable and $table, how should be this create function?

Comment: create method is part of the Model class. Easy way is to use the create method directly: `$item = App\Item::create($request->old());`